# How can I link Entry and Button widgets in Tkinter with classes?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ï'm trying to make a simple code that can automatically perform a sequence of smaller tasks on the click of a button. There's some information that currently needs to be punched into several word and excel sheets and webpages at work; it's time consuming and boring. My idea has been to create a tkinter window that allows the user to enter the necessary information, which is subsequently stored in a .csv file. I made it work without the use of classes, but when researching Tkinter, I realised that it's good practise to use classes. Problem is, I can't make it work when I put the entry widget into a class. This code works, but doesn't apply class(es):

```
def newprojectinput():
    task_number_s = task_number_e.get()
    #code is written to .csv in this method

my_window = Tk()

generate_b = Button(my_window, text="Make new project", command=newprojectinput)
generate_b.grid(row=12,column=1)

task_number_e = Entry(my_window)
task_number_e.grid(row=0,column=1)
my_window.mainloop()
```

This doesn't work:

```
def newprojectinput():
    task_number_s = task_number_e.get()
    #code is written to .csv in this method

class Toplevel_new_project:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        self.Frame1 = tk.Frame(top)
        self.task_number_e = tk.Entry(self.Frame1)
        self.generate_b = tk.Button(self.Frame1, command=newprojectinput)
```

I would appreciate it if someone could take the time to provide optimal code and maybe briefly explain why the previous code doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? What is it doing, and how is it different from what you expect? Is it giving wrong results? Is it throwing an error? If it's throwing an error, what is the error?

Comment: Thanks for asking. In the second example, it throws a NameError: name 'task_number_e' is not defined.

Comment: @Christoffer: Make your `def newprojectinput():` a class methode `def newprojectinput(self):` and change `task_number_e.get()` to `self. task_number_e.get()`. Exercise [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the help stovl and for the link to the exercise